# AngularJS - How to refresh data in cacheFactory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `$cacheFactory`, I like it because it will increase performance by not calling service data all the times. But my doubt is on update of existing data, how can I update `$cacheFactory` data

```
service.query = function(queryCriteria) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: BASE_URL + '/ticketCategories' + '?' + ApplicationUtil.parseQueryCriteria(queryCriteria),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': APP_CONSTANTS.STRATAGIES.BEARER + ' ' + ApplicationStorage.getJwtToken()
    },
    cache: true
  };
  var cache = $cacheFactory(Math.random());
  var data = cache.get("ticketCategories");
  if (!data) {
    $http(req).then(function(payload) {
      deferred.resolve(payload.data);
      cache.put("ticketCategories", payload.data);
    }, function(reason) {
      Logger.error(reason, 'Error querying ticket categories');
      deferred.reject(reason);
    });
  } else {
    return data;
  }
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample implementation using your code could look like this.

```
var cache = $cacheFactory(Math.random());

service.query = function(queryCriteria) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: BASE_URL + '/ticketCategories' + '?' + ApplicationUtil.parseQueryCriteria(queryCriteria),
        headers: {
            'Authorization': APP_CONSTANTS.STRATAGIES.BEARER + ' ' + ApplicationStorage.getJwtToken()
        },
        cache: true
    };
    var data = cache.get("ticketCategories");
    if (!data) {
        $http(req).then(function(payload) {
            deferred.resolve(payload.data);
            cache.put("ticketCategories", payload.data);
        }, function(reason) {
            Logger.error(reason, 'Error querying ticket categories');
            deferred.reject(reason);
        });
    } else {
        return data;
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};

service.refresh = function (queryCriteria) {
    // removes all cached entries
    cache.removeAll();
    // force reload, still returns the promise
    return service.query(queryCriteria);
};
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. If I put more data in cacheFactory like `ticketCategories`, `tickets`, `faqs`. Suggest in that case

Comment: You can also remove elements from cache by id. That would look like this: `cache.remove('ticketCategories');` in your case. Read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache)